# Angular trigger sibling component function get TypeError: Cannot read property XX of undefined

Tags: angular

In my landing component I have 2 child component A child and B child.
My A child component need to trigger B child however get Cannot read property 'test'of undefined

*landing.component.html*

```
<div>
  <app-a-child></app-a-child>
  <app-b-child></app-b-child>
</div>
```

*app-a-child.component.ts*

```
import { AppBChildComponent } from '../app-b-child/app-b-child.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-a-child',
  template: '<button (click)="onClickTrigger()"> Click to Trigger B function</button>',
})
export class AppAChildComponent {
  @ViewChild('appBChildComponent', { static: true}) _appBChild: AppBChildComponent;

constructor() {}

public onClickTrigger(): void{
  this._appBChild.test();
}
```

*app-b-child.component.ts*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-b-child',
  template: '<p>{{ text }}</p>',
})
export class AppBChildComponent {
text = '';

constructor() {}

public test(): void {
    text = 'You have success trigger B function ');
    console.log(test);
    this.nextFunction();
 }

public nextFunction(): void {
  ....
}

}
```

So when i call onClickTrigger() from A child component , will get error of Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'test' of undefined at app-a-child-component.ts

Comment: `B` not a child of A, you landing page would be able to do this

Comment: if i want to from inside A child trigger B child function, have any other method?

Comment: Either use services to do this or emit something to landing page and then upon receiving an event the landing page would this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to pass data between components who have no parent/child realtionship is with services using observables. Here is a helpfull link for obersavbles:  https://medium.com/@luukgruijs/understanding-creating-and-subscribing-to-observables-in-angular-426dbf0b04a3